# CASE for joining sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need a help on sql database side. And i have

table 1 : ENTITY_TYPE

```
entity_type_id  entity_name
     1            Task
     2            Page
     3            Project
     4            Message
     5            User
```

and table 2 : MESSAGE , that contains message from each entity values like

```
message_id entity_type owner_tableid message
    1           1             12       A message on task level
    2           3             14       A message on project level
```

and I want select these message according to each entity type and details from its owner table using 'owner_tableid'   ie a query like....

```
select * from MESSAGE JOIN
case entity_type when 1 then taskTable
when 2 then pageTable
when 3 then projectTable
when 4 then MessageTable
when 5 then UserTable
```

Which is best method to solve this issue on single procedure. Any idea ?? Now I am using IF clause for each entity...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't parameterise the *tables* involved in a query (so you can't put a table name in a variable and expect that to be used either).

One way to do it is as a chain of left joins:

```
select
  * /* TODO - Pick columns */
from
   MESSAGE m
      left join
   taskTable tt
      on
         m.entity_type = 1 and
         m.owner_entity_id = tt.id
      left join
   pageTable pt
      on
         m.entity_type = 2 and
         m.owner_entity_id = pt.id
      left join
   projectTable prt
      on
         m.entity_type = 3 and
         m.owner_entity_id = prt.id
      left join
   MessageTable mt
      on
         m.entity_type = 4 and
         m.owner_entity_id = mt.id
      left join
   UserTable ut
      on
         m.entity_type = 5 and
         m.owner_entity_id = ut.id
```

If you want values from these tables to appear in a single column in the result, use a `COALESCE` across all of the values, e.g.

```
COALESCE(tt.Value,pt.Value,prt.Value,mt.Value,ut.Value) as Value
```

Comment: Am I the only one that finds this layout difficult to read? It's like try to read code written on a Jenga puzzle. +1 because the solution is a viable answer; just very hard to read.

Comment: I like this solution. But, if there is many entity types we want to create a very big query. If there is any simple way that using view, pivot ... etc in query.

Answer (score 1):

Use Union Clause with your individual entity_type

```
SELECT * FROM Message
JOIN pageTable ON ....
WHERE entity_type = 1

UNION ALL
..........
entity_type = 2

UNION ALL
..........
entity_type = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return several entity_types details in one query, than `UNION` might help:

```
SELECT interesting_columns FROM Message
JOIN pageTable ON (joinPredicate)
WHERE entity_type = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT interesting_columns FROM Message
JOIN pageTable ON (joinPredicate)
WHERE entity_type = 2

-- ...
```

But if you only need details of certain entity_type than you original solution with `IF` would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  ...
From Message
    Join    (
            Select 1 As entity_type, id
            From taskTable
            Union All
            Select 2, id
            From pageTable
            Union All
            Select 3, id
            From projectTable
            Union All
            Select 4, id
            From messageTable
            Union All
            Select 5, id
            From userTable
            ) As Z
        On Z.entity_type = Message.entity_type
            And Z.id = Message.owner_tableid
```